# Singly linked list using template with a struct as elements in C++;

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a linked list to store student's informations, with Student is a struct like this:

```
struct Student
{
    int id;
    string name;
    //etc
};
```

I have two templates for node and list with a basic function:

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node <T> *pNext;
    Node () : pNext(NULL) {}
    Node (T &a) : data(a), pNext(NULL) {}
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    Node <T> *Head;
    size_t lSize;
public:
    LinkedList(): Head(NULL), lSize(0) {}
    ~LinkedList();

    void linsert(T& a);
};
```

With *linsert()* to insert new node at the beginning of the list:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::linsert(T& a)
{
    if (Head==nullptr)
        Head=a;
    else
    {
        a->pNext=Head;
        Head=a;
    }
    lSize++;
}
```

To the testing: I've tried creating new nodes and linking them manually (without using the linked list) and everything seems to work fine:

```
Node <Student> *s1 = new Node <Student>;
s1->data.id=1;
s1->data.name="Anna";

Node <Student> *s2 = new Node <Student>;
s2->data.id=2;
s2->data.name="Bob";
s1->pNext=s2;

Node <Student> *s3 = new Node <Student>;
s3->data.id=3;
s3->data.name="James";
s2->pNext=s3;
```

Here's the problem: I tried creating a new linked list, and use the *linsert()* to add new students to the list with a simple for loop:

```
LinkedList <Node<Student>> *l=new LinkedList <Node<Student>>;

for (int=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Node <Student> *s = new Node <Student>;
    s->data.id=i;
    s->data.name="Name";

    l->linsert(s);
}
```

When compile, I get this error message points to the line

```
l->linsert(s);
```

```
error: no matching function for call to 'LinkedList<Node<Student> >::linsert(Node<Student>*&)'
note: candicate: void LinkedList<T>::linsert(T&) [With T=Node<Student>]
note: no known conversion from argument 1 from 'Node<Student>*' to 'Node<Student>&'
```

I always have problem using pointer and reference so after a good hour not figuring anything out I gave up. Please help me to solve this.

I'm using CodeBlock and if there's any improvement I can make for the above codes, it would be appreciated if you could tell me.

Comment: `LinkedList <Student>` Note how the `T` is applied to the `Node` members of `LinkedList`

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `LinkedList<Student>`?

Comment: Unrelated: `LinkedList <Student> *l=new LinkedList <Student>;` could be (and probably should be) `LinkedList <Student> l;` [Avoid `new`ing stuff unless forced to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `linsert()` is implemented incorrectly. It should take a `Student` as input and create a new node for it. You are trying to create nodes outside of `linsert()` and pass them in, which is not the right way to use linked list classes. The node management should be kept inside the class.

Try this instead:

```cpp
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::linsert(T& a)
{
    Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(a);
    n->pNext = Head;
    Head = n;
    ++lSize;
}
```

```cpp
LinkedList<Student> l;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Student s;
    s.id = i;
    s.name = "Name";
    l.linsert(s);
}
```